# Java pass collection as parameter not adding to acctual reference

Tags: java, android, collections, parameters, pass-by-reference

I have my activity register with my service as a listener, and on some events I pass the collection held internally in the service, which has worked great for reading the collection to display with my list adapter. However, now I want to add to the collection in my callback, but its not working like the reference I thought it was!

```
//last param tells service to send the list
//first param sets listener that recieves the sent list
m_uploader.request(new RequestListener() {

    @Override
    public void getCompletedUploads(ArrayList<Job> completed) { 
       //dont care
    }

    @Override
    public void getActiveUploads(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Job> current) {
        current.add(m_job); //doesnt add to queue in my service
        ImportActivity.this.finish();
    }

}, ServiceRequestArgs.create(RequestActiveUploadsCommand.class)); 

//impl of request()
public <T extends ICommand> void request(
    IFileUploadListener listener, ServiceRequestArgs<T> args) 
{
    if (args.getClassToken().equals(RequestActiveUploadsCommand.class))
        new RequestActiveUploadsCommand(listener, m_jobQueue).Execute();
    if (args.getClassToken().equals(RequestCompleteUploadsCommand.class))
        new RequestCompleteUploadsCommand(listener, m_completedList).Execute();
        //calls getActiveUploads on listener
}
```

**edit** Ok, so I am definately just passing the value of the reference. Java hating aside, how do I change the acctual reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `current.add` should be adding a new `Job` to the queue like you expect.

However, Java's Concurrent collections have some special properties.  One is that an `Iterator` returned by a Concurrent collection is [*weakly consistent*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility): it may or may not reflect changes made to the collection since the iterator was created.

This applies to both `Iterator`s you manually request and ones that are automatically created as part of a for-each.

Comment: Oh, word. I suppose I could change it to PriorityQueue and synchronize the add. Would you.. concur?

Comment: ACK! I've been punned!  But yeah, it's worth a try.

Comment: PriorityQueue didnt work for me either, I am just going to add a method to my IBinder...